# Image appearing and disappearing with CSS hover

Tags: html, css, image

I am working on a drop down menu that I want to make completely with CSS. Within the link I will not only have text that needs to change when hovered over, but also an image. Changing the color of the text is easy. However I am not sure how to swap the images on the hover...

Here is what I want the result to look like:

[image: End result]

Where the arrows will be small images that will switch when the link is hovered over. How do I do this using CSS?

Comment: can you post html/css and a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Check **Image Sprites - Hover Effect** section.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS `background: url()...` on an element you deem most applicable. Here is documentation and a walkthrough: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background.

On a side-note, you may want to consider using a sprite as well, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Image_Sprites

Answer (score 0):

Set the image as a background image to a div (with a set width and height), and you can change that value with css.

Ideally put both graphics into one image, so that you can just shift the background position and you don't get any flicker during the transition (Google "css image sprites").

I believe you'd need to use javascript to change the src of an embedded image.

You could also have two images and use display:block and display:none to show/hide them as appropriate, but I don't think that would be the best approach.